# A good pattern for complex search criteria?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I am currently working on a user search function.
The search criteria are quite complex, for example:

```
Footage >= 50 AND (SizeCode == SizeType.Large OR MobileEnd == "ABC")
```

I think that the Criteria/Filter Pattern could be suitable for this function. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criteria_Pattern

My questions are:
How can I add parameters into the MeetCriteria()? 
I need some functions like:

```
public List<Store> MeetCriteria(List<Store> entities, int footage)

public List<Store> MeetCriteria(List<Store> entities, string mobileEnd)
```

The parenthesis is a trouble to parse. Is it a good idea to design interface as "standard form" (using OR only in the top level), so that the above search criteria can be accepted as:

```
(Footage >= 50 AND SizeCode == SizeType.Large) OR 
(Footage >= 50 AND MobileEnd == "ABC")
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR**

I believe in general, this problem is best solved in C# using LINQ. Specifically, if the criteria are to be translated into SQL and applied against a database, then the criteria can be expressed as Expression trees, as these can be processed provided by query providers like Entity Framework.

**Rationale:**

IMO if you try and build your own Criteria or [Evans specification pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern) from scratch, as you've suggested, you will need to build an model or language for defining your criteria, be able to parse this model (including handling order of precedence etc), and possibly also translate this into Sql or other data query language to execute the criteria efficiently. This will be a long and painful journey IMO.

Here's a simple example using `Func<Store, bool>` predicates to build up criteria and execute them against a static in-memory collection. This is by no means complete - all this does is exact matches with `And`, although does allow for optional filtering:

```
private static readonly IEnumerable<Store> _myStores = new[]
{
    new Store {Footage = 100, MobileEnd = "XYZ", SizeCode = SizeCode.Small},
    new Store {Footage = 200, MobileEnd = "XYZ", SizeCode = SizeCode.Medium},
    new Store {Footage = 300, MobileEnd = "XYZ", SizeCode = SizeCode.Large},
    new Store {Footage = 150, MobileEnd = "ABC", SizeCode = SizeCode.Small},
    new Store {Footage = 250, MobileEnd = "ABC", SizeCode = SizeCode.Medium},
    new Store {Footage = 350, MobileEnd = "ABC", SizeCode = SizeCode.Large},
};

private static IEnumerable<Store> ApplyAndPredicates(IEnumerable<Func<Store, bool>> predicates)
{
    var filteredStores = _myStores;
    foreach (var predicate in predicates)
    {
        filteredStores = filteredStores.Where(predicate);
    }
    return filteredStores;
}

public static List<Store> MeetCriteria(List<Store> entities, int? footage = null, string mobileEnd = null, SizeCode? sizeCode = null)
{
    var predicates = new List<Func<Store, bool>>();
    if (footage.HasValue)
    {
        predicates.Add(s => s.Footage == footage.Value);
    }
    if (mobileEnd != null)
    {
        predicates.Add(s => s.MobileEnd == mobileEnd);
    }
    if (sizeCode != null)
    {
        predicates.Add(s => s.SizeCode == sizeCode);
    }
    return ApplyAndPredicates(predicates).ToList();
}
```

**Edit**
The point I am trying to argue is that LINQ Expression Trees already provide a type-safe, expressive, Sql-Injection-proof DSL for expressing any Criteria / Specification pattern. I would recommend you convert presentation tier queries into strongly typed `IQueryable<T>`'s as soon as possible, thus averting the need for any custom criteria language / DSL.

Some validation of queries will still be required, e.g. to prevent users from executing arbitrary queries and e.g. returning the whole table.

If your physical architecture has a serialization interface across the layers, look at using [OData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh237663.aspx) representations of your queries - this addresses the issue of how to do a serialization / deserialization cycle of  predicates / criteria.

Comment: It's a good idea to use LINQ and delegate, instead of the ICriteria interface. 
But I don't figure out how to deal with NOT, AND, OR logic. It looks like I still need an interpreter to convert user input into a LINQ expression. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Specification pattern is another candidate:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern . It let you build more criteria on top of existing criteria.

Here is how you would use it:

```
var OverDue = new OverDueSpecification();
var NoticeSent = new NoticeSentSpecification();
var InCollection = new InCollectionSpecification();

// example of specification pattern logic chaining
var SendToCollection = OverDue.And(NoticeSent).And(InCollection.Not());

var InvoiceCollection = Service.GetInvoices();

foreach (var currentInvoice in InvoiceCollection) {
    if (SendToCollection.IsSatisfiedBy(currentInvoice))  {
        currentInvoice.SendToCollection();
    }
}
```

and the generic code in C# 6.0:

```
  public interface ISpecification<T>
    {
        bool IsSatisfiedBy(T candidate);
        ISpecification<T> And(ISpecification<T> other);
        ISpecification<T> AndNot(ISpecification<T> other);
        ISpecification<T> Or(ISpecification<T> other);
        ISpecification<T> OrNot(ISpecification<T> other);
        ISpecification<T> Not();
    }

    public abstract class LinqSpecification<T> : CompositeSpecification<T>
    {
        public abstract Expression<Func<T, bool>> AsExpression();
        public override bool IsSatisfiedBy(T candidate) => AsExpression().Compile()(candidate);
    }

    public abstract class CompositeSpecification<T> : ISpecification<T>
    {
        public abstract bool IsSatisfiedBy(T candidate);
        public ISpecification<T> And(ISpecification<T> other) => new AndSpecification<T>(this, other);
        public ISpecification<T> AndNot(ISpecification<T> other) => new AndNotSpecification<T>(this, other);
        public ISpecification<T> Or(ISpecification<T> other) => new OrSpecification<T>(this, other);
        public ISpecification<T> OrNot(ISpecification<T> other) => new OrNotSpecification<T>(this, other);
        public ISpecification<T> Not() => new NotSpecification<T>(this);
    }

    public class AndSpecification<T> : CompositeSpecification<T>
    {
        ISpecification<T> left;
        ISpecification<T> right;

        public AndSpecification(ISpecification<T> left, ISpecification<T> right)
        {
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
        }

        public override bool IsSatisfiedBy(T candidate) => left.IsSatisfiedBy(candidate) && right.IsSatisfiedBy(candidate);
    }

    public class AndNotSpecification<T> : CompositeSpecification<T>
    {
        ISpecification<T> left;
        ISpecification<T> right;

        public AndNotSpecification(ISpecification<T> left, ISpecification<T> right)
        {
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
        }

        public override bool IsSatisfiedBy(T candidate) => left.IsSatisfiedBy(candidate) && right.IsSatisfiedBy(candidate) != true;
    }

    public class OrSpecification<T> : CompositeSpecification<T>
    {
        ISpecification<T> left;
        ISpecification<T> right;

        public OrSpecification(ISpecification<T> left, ISpecification<T> right)
        {
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
        }

        public override bool IsSatisfiedBy(T candidate) => left.IsSatisfiedBy(candidate) || right.IsSatisfiedBy(candidate);
    }
    public class OrNotSpecification<T> : CompositeSpecification<T>
    {
        ISpecification<T> left;
        ISpecification<T> right;

        public OrNotSpecification(ISpecification<T> left, ISpecification<T> right)
        {
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
        }

        public override bool IsSatisfiedBy(T candidate) => left.IsSatisfiedBy(candidate) || right.IsSatisfiedBy(candidate) != true;
    }

    public class NotSpecification<T> : CompositeSpecification<T>
    {
        ISpecification<T> other;
        public NotSpecification(ISpecification<T> other) => this.other = other;
        public override bool IsSatisfiedBy(T candidate) => !other.IsSatisfiedBy(candidate);
    }
```

References:

- Specifications design pattern: http://www.martinfowler.com/apsupp/spec.pdf